# How should I solve nonlinear equation with R

Tags: r

I would like to ask you how can I solve such nonlinear equation with R? EL and DR are given values. I only want to get alpha.

[image: nonlinear equation]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your equation can be quickly reduced by hand to `alpha = 1 / (1 - 0.05*DR/EL)`, which effectively removes the need to solve it with software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out the [`nleqslv`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nleqslv/) package, or otherwise the [`BB`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BB/) package.

Be careful, though, as they have some unstated (in the documentation as far as I have read it) continuity requirements on the equations.

Comment: Both packages are dedicated to systems of equations not single ones.. Am I right?

Comment: Well, yes. But a "system" of 1 equation should work just fine. Admittedly: I haven't tried this.

Comment: You're absolutely right - sorry for my previous post! I am wondering whether there is a package that gives me all roots of the equation...